# Is this an example of overfitting?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, overfitting, k-nearest-neighbour, concept-drift

I am trying to predict some future values using either KNN or regression model.
I have about 9 independent variables that do not seem to have strong correlation to each other (Not completely sure though). Sample size is around 70.

The graph is as follows.

[image]

Blue line is the true value where as the yellow line is the prediction. As you can see, the yellow line fluctuates too much. I am guessing that it is happening due to overfitting.

Are there any methods I can use to make this more natrual and fitting to the actual values other than to add more samples? (I cannot access more data unfortunately :(   )

If indeed this is the case of overfitting, I do not really know how to deal with it. Is anyone willing to share their knowledge?

Comment: Have you tried reducing the complexity of your models (e.g: increase k in k-nn or lesser degree polynomials in regression)? Make sure you use a proper training-testing procedure. Else you cannot tell if you are overfitting.

Comment: It looks to me as if your models had excessive complexity (this has already been pointed out by a previous answer) Could you please provide further information about model specifications and the data you use to train your model?